# DateTime Globalization in ASP.NET MVC and SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC app, ModelState is always invalid with the following error message: `"The value '5/23/2015 7:29:37 AM' is not valid for Register Date."`

I'm trying to localize my app for Persian culture, so I set `uiCulture` and `culture` to `fa-IR` in the `web.config`. Still, `DateTime.Now` doesn't return localized date.

What's the correct way to globalize `DateTime`? Should I store localized date in DB? Or the localized version is just for views?

It seems I'm supposed to store localized version in DB, how can I get that for Persian culture?

**UPDATE:**

It seems I can't get current Persian date directly and I have to convert it as stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You cannot use a PersianCalendar object as the default calendar for a culture. The default calendar is specified by the CultureInfo.Calendar property and must be one of the calendars returned by the CultureInfo.OptionalCalendars property. Currently, the PersianCalendar class is not an optional calendar for any culture supported by the CultureInfo class and consequently cannot be a default calendar.

Bu how can I know which component is adding the error message and how can I fix it?

Comment: storing UTC  in DB is the best way.. then you can do the conversion logic in application code

Comment: So, why my ModelState is always invalid because of DateTime?

Comment: Are you using a jquery datepicker plugin to select the date, and if so have you used `jquery.globalize.js`?

Comment: Currently, I'm using `DateTime.Now` in my controller to insert current time. So, user doesn't enter the date. But my app uses Kendo. That will be the next painful step, to have a globalized date picker.

Comment: If user doesn't enter the date on your model why don't you change your model to use nullable date time  `DateTime?`. Have you try it? Does error still exist?

Comment: It's already nullable. How can I understand which component is adding the error? Kendo, MVC Binder, or what?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you localize your date on the client side, and not on the server or database side. This way, you're never bound to a specific culture. For instance, your date could be expressed this way : "2015-05-23T7:29:37Z".

I also suggest you save and send your datetimes in UTC.

Comment: Thanks, but why my ModelState is always invalid because of date time? I thought I'm supposed to store it on DB. How can I know what component is adding that specific error message?